# how do I return value to error case in jasmine-mocking a promise?

Tags: jasmine, promise

I am mocking a method that returns value to a promise. I am successful in returning value to positive case but can't seem to return value to negative case. I return value to success case by

```
return {
  then: function (callback) {
    return callback({'foo' : "bar"});
            }
        };
```

the method I am mocking (below)

```
login() {
  return axios.post("/login");
}
```

returns control to

```
login().then((response) => {
    console.log("correct",response);
  }, (err)=> {
    console.log("wrong response",err);
  });
```

Comment: can you please add more code? what exactly are you testing and what are you mocking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never roll your own `then`ables like that - that's very risky.

That said, if you must, you can do :

```
then: function (success, fail) {
  return fail(Error("Error"));
};
```

But why bother? You can do:

```
return Promise.reject(Error("Error"));
```

Which is a lot simpler and less error prone, similarly for success:

```
return Promise.resolve({a: 'a', b: 'b'});
```